# Autocompletion using Html tags and servlets

Tags: java, html, servlets, autocomplete

I Am trying to do autocompletion by reading text from a file. its running fine in swings. I want to run it on server. Have used Html tags and servlets its working but when I enter query after pressing enter its showing me matching list 
How can I make it autocomplete should I make use of threads or any Html tag for autocompletion. I dont have much understanding of coding. Please help me in this
Here is my servlet code

NewServlet.java

```
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

 public NewServlet() {

    }
 String json;

   ArrayList<String> match = new ArrayList<String>();

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    //  response.setContentType("application/json");
    AutoTest1 t = new AutoTest1();
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    Trie suggestions = new Trie();
    String fileName =  "C:/Users/USER/Documents/NetBeansProjects/HelloWorld/web/WEB-INF/aol.txt";
    words = t.readWordsFromFile(fileName);
    Trie trie = new Trie();

    for (String word : words) {
        trie.insert(word);
    }
    suggestions = trie;
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String prefix = request.getParameter("term");

        ArrayList<String> matchingSuggestions = suggestions.getAllPrefixMatches(prefix);

        //final List<AutoCompleteData> result = new ArrayList<AutoCompleteData>();
        for (String suggestion : matchingSuggestions) {
            json = gson.toJson(suggestion);
            // result.add(new AutoCompleteData(suggestion,suggestion));

        }
          response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        //  response.getWriter().write("<option>"+new Gson().toJson(result)+"<option>");      // Write response body.

        response.getWriter().write(json);
       }

    }

  }
```

autocomplete.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<script      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({     
        source : function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
                url : "NewServlet",
                type : "GET",
                data : {
                        term : request.term
                },
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                        response(data);
                }
             });
            }
          });
       });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
      <div class="search-container">
            <div class="ui-widget">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="search" />
            </div>
      </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: its better to use a JSP and then fire some Ajax call on keypress to get the suggestions rather than submitting the form every time. You can write all your HTML code inside JSP and you JavaScript to bind some event handler to fire the call.

Comment: you don't have to invoke java class and methods from your jsp, your form has some action `NewServlet`, so doing a form submit will come to the same servlet or a you can configure a different url to go to different one. You're writing your html code in `println()` escaping quotes, instead of struggling so much you can write your html in your jsp and then use your servlet to forward control to that jsp :)

Comment: yeah i can write seperate html and after request it goes to servlets. just to show 1 block of code i included in println(). if i use datalist tag which is for autocompletion how can i put list in options of datalist.

Comment: Now we're talking.. I thought of suggesting datalist to u :-).. Have another servlet configured and on key press in text box fire an ajax call to get the option tags and replace the datalist inner html..

Comment: can you please provide sample code on this or any link or tutorial.

Comment: A quick search in google gives these links - [link1](http://www.javatutorials.co.in/servlet-3-ajax-hello-world-example-using-jquery/) and  [link2](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/09/jquery-ajax-servlets-integration-building-a-complete-application.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can always define a new servlet in web.xml and call that in an AJAX call to return the suggestions.

If your're using jQuery, you can do something like this

**main.jsp**

```
<input type="text" list="suggestions" class="inputBox"/>

<datalist id="suggestions">
  <option value=" Loading...">
</datalist>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.inputBox').on('keyup',function(){
         $.ajax({
            url : 'yourServletAction'
            data : {'query' : $(this).val()}
         }).done(function(data,jqXHR){
             $('#suggestions').html(data);
         });
      }); 
    )};
</script>
```

On Server Side in your `doGet()`, based on the `query` parameter, you'll populate the suggestions in an ArrayList and save that as a request attribute like this

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException,IOException{
        String prefix =request.getParameter("query");
        ArrayList<String> matchingSuggestions =  suggestions.getAllPrefixMatches(prefix);

        request.setAttribute("suggestions",matchingSuggestions);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/suggest.jsp");
        rd.forward(request,response);

    }
```

Now that the control goes to `suggest.jsp`, we can use JSTL (download from [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.1/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar)) to loop over the list and send the options. In fact you can send JSON back by using Jackson library, but I'm sensing that it's too much to digest at the moment

**suggest.jsp**

```
<c:forEach items="${suggestions}" var="suggestion">
   <option value="${suggestion}" />
</c:forEach>
```

This should give you some start :)

Comment: Ideally you're supposed to post a new question explaining what you've done and the part of your code which you think is not working. Pls do that and post the link in the comments and many others will try to help you not just me :-)

Comment: Did you check if there are any script errors in Developer Tools console ? If no errors, check if your Ajax call is firing by checking Network tab in dev tools

Comment: Chrome - F12- Dev Tools - Network tab - Filter by XHR

Comment: then your Ajax url might be wrong. Click on your Ajax call in Network tab and see `Request URL` in `Headers` section

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using relative path in `src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"` ? You used full path for other scripts.

Comment: when you mention relative path, full path is resolved against current window URL. For example, if you have `http://localhost:8080/MyServlet/index` in your current window, then the url for script will be `http://localhost:8080/MyServlet/indexjs/jquery.autocomplete.js`, it will simply append that without adding any slashes. So check if your resolved script url is correct. You can check the same in `RequestURL` in Network tab for your script, just remove filter by XHR and select All

Comment: I mean you used full path for jquery.ui.js like this `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js` but not for `jquer.autocomplete.js`. Any reason for that ? I think that's the reason you're getting 404 for that as you're loading all the other files from CDNs

Comment: Ya look for jquery.autocomplete.js in CDNs. They will be always available. Also where exactly are you using that plugin ? If you're not using remove that script tag and in your success callback, you're calling `response()`. Is it defined somewhere else ?

Comment: I resolved that error by placing it in proper folder. now its not giving me error. but also not giving me output

Comment: Is your Ajax call working now ? What is the server response you see in Network - Preview tab for your call ? Any js errors in console ? You don't have enough rep else I would have initiated some chat

Comment: no ajax is not calling i think so bcoz its exiting in jquery.ui.js.  no any errors

Comment: Oops I didn't see your code properly, i can see where you're using auto complete. That plugin expects response in some particular format. Check if its correct

Comment: Can you post the res you're getting in that ajax call ? It should be an array of strings as mentioned [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)